# How to add sub-headers to menu using fxml files?

Tags: javafx, menu, fxml

How do I add sub-headers to my menu using JavaFX and the fxml files? I have looked at the CustomMenuItem option but I am unable to figure out what to put in the content part. Thanks for your help!

My fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<MenuBar>
    <menus>
        <Menu text="Menu 1">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="Item 1" />
                <MenuItem text="Item 2" />
                <MenuItem text="Item 3" />
                <SeparatorMenuItem />
                <MenuItem text="Item A" />
                <MenuItem text="Item B" />
                <MenuItem text="Item C" />
            </items>
        </Menu>
    </menus>
</MenuBar>
```

Below is an example of the result I am looking for. "Header 1" and "Header 2" shouldn't be clickable and should not highlight when the mouse moves over them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your input. Based on the link you provided, I found that it simply can be done adding the following in the fxml file:

```
<SeparatorMenuItem>
    <content>
        <Text text="Header Name"  styleClass="textSeparator" />
    </content>
</SeparatorMenuItem>
```

Comment: By the way: this doesn't work on Macs. Instead a normal separator will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for is here:

http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/2013/01/02/creating-custom-menu-separator-in-javafx/